# How to make auto-suggest work with nested functions that use *args and **kwargs

Tags: python

Suppose I have

```
def outside_func(*args, **kwargs):
    blah
    innner_func(*args, **kwargs)

def inner_func(distance=3, scatterer_stregth=4):
    blah
```

When running the outside function and feeding arguments to it, I don't get suggestions. Is there any way to get those? Or is there any programming tip to avoid this in the first place.

Comment: This would likely depend on whatever editor or IDE you are using.

Comment: @Keldorn Pycharm